# mpandroidchart LimitLine set transparent line and change label color

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

(This question was for MPAndroidChart-1.7.4)

I love using the `mpandroidchart` library to create graphic plotting for my android app, but I am experiencing some difficulties with the `LimitLine` object right now. I am trying to set the line to be `transparent` and the label to be white with bigger font. Is it possible? I know there is no existing methods can do that right now, but just wondering if there is any way I can customize it myself? Any help would be great! Thanks.

Note: This is my first post so I can not attach an image here. I hope my question is clear to those who has experience with `mpandroidchart`.

```
LimitLine ll1 = new LimitLine((float) (values[1]*maxFactor));
ll1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
ll1.setDrawValue(true);
ll1.setLineColor(res.getColor(R.color.new_orange));
ll1.setLabelPosition(LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT);
```

Comment: So now I just need help to change the LimitLine label font, thanks for any help!

Comment: MPAndroidChart-2.0.9 fixes this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with:
`ll1.setLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));`

Please define first the transparent color:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

The color of the label is the same of the line. So, you can't change for white, and the line for transparent in the same time.

For change the font, you can do this for all chart.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
chart.setValueTypeface(tf);
chart.setCenterTextTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Light.ttf"));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my two questions. Maybe I should separate the problem into two so I can give credit to the one who can answer just one of my questions. Anyway, will remember and do that next time. For your answer, the line now becomes black instead of transparent. Maybe another thought? Thanks.

Comment: Actually the correct way is to use ll1.setLineColor(res.getColor(android.R.color.transparent)); Thanks for giving me the hint =]

Comment: My answer is correct :)
The color of the label is the same of the line. So, you can't change for white, and the line for transparent

Please change the post, to resolve :)